# iPhone: Which encoding scheme should be used in importing CSV file into Sqlite database

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, character-encoding, ios-4.2

In my iPhone app, I am importing CSV file into SQlite database using CHCSV parser.

My CSV file contains data in European Languages containing special characters like umlaut, etc.

Which encoding should I use?

Should it be UTF8StringEncoding or some other encoding scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What encoding is the original file in? Because that's the encoding you should use. CSV doesn't define any specific encoding, so it really depends on how the file was created.

Comment: Ballard: Thanks for the input. Original encoding is UTF8. I tried importing CSV using UTF8 encoding scheme but the data is not imported from CSV in that case. What could be wrong?

Comment: I really can't begin to try and debug a third-party software that I've never seen. If the file is loaded using the correct encoding, and if you can verify that the file data is actually being read by your program and looks correct, then I would assume it's an issue with CHCSV itself.

Comment: Nope Kevin CHCSV is fine. It was my mistake at one of the places I didnt put the encoding value and hence i was missing out on some data. Thanks for the input though. :)